# How can i find duplicate name/value in SAME row? is it possible to count it?

Tags: c#, mysql, excel

for exmaple there is 1 colonm named "Name" and i am entering name "David David" (twice) so if i search it with count(*) where name="David" , it returns 1 and is that possible to get the count as 2? how is that possible? i am also searching the same name/value in different rows and tables too and finally adding the count so please help

Answer (score 2):

This will work in MS Access.

```
SELECT Sum((Len([Name])-Len(Replace([Name],'David','')))/Len('David')) AS name_count
FROM   YOUR_TABLE
WHERE  YOUR_TABLE.Name Like "*David*";
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but actually my database is in MsAccess 2003 so LENGTH function is not working ,how can i get this query to work in that case?

Comment: and actually i am searching for file not name like "01.jpg" and i am using Ck editor to save the content/files

Comment: You should remove C# and mysql from the tags for this question and add MS Access.

Comment: thanks for the answer i'll try this query and NO i am using this database in my website sir thats why i used C# and i didnt add more tags bcz i just needed the query

Comment: WHOA THANK YOU SOOOO MUCH IT WORKED!!!! :') sorry i cant vote this answer bcz my reputation is too low :/

Comment: i havent added this query to my Page but i got what i needed thanks again :)

Comment: hey Tom i get this error while implementing this query into my C# page "Undefined function 'Replace' in expression." so how can i get this worked on my page? :/ please help (i have use OleDbConnection)

Comment: Sorry, I was able to run this in Access.  I'm not sure why you can't run it through C#.  Can you try another connection method?

Comment: No i have to use access database And "Replace" function won't work in C# i have searched it :( but thanks anyway if u find any solution for this problem please let me know

Answer (score 0):

How about having a count of "David David" and adding this onto your other count. Would that achieve what you're after?

Comment: nah that's not the proper solution mate

Comment: @Dane this is not a solution, u can post it as a comment after getting 50 reputation

Answer (score 0):

you can use group by

```
SELECT Name,
       COUNT (Name) as count
FROM tablename
WHERE Name='Devid'
GROUP BY Name;
```

Comment: @Romil r u entering "Devid Devid" in a single row? or are you entering the same value in different row? if u are entering it in different row then i think my query will give you the duplicate count

Comment: yes i am entering "David David" in single row and actually i am using Ck Editor to save the content so it'll allow u to save the file/name in same row

Comment: @Romil ow sorry so its my mistake i think you are entering to different row and try to find its count

Comment: @Romil in sql  you can use some split functionality for achieving this . Ms access also support split functionality,you can check the strings are equal after split with space and count that if it is same